# UISearchBar embedded in UIBarButtonItems (IT IS iPad document!)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar, uitoolbar, size-classes

I had `UISearchBar` embedded in `UIBarButtonItems` for a years in the iPad storyboard. Now when I turn **Use Size Classes** on, the storyboard (which is using exclusively for iPad), throw the compilation time error:

> UISearchBar embedded in UIBarButtonItems (Only available in iPad
>   documents)

Is there any way to let XCode know that the storyboard is using with iPad only!?

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug with Xcode. Apple fixed the bug in Xcode 8.2. Now you can use `UISearchBar` in `UIToolbar` in adaptive storyboards.

Comment: I was forced to use one adaptive storyboard instead of 2 storyboards (one for iPad and one for iPhone) because of this and other issues. It was a quite a big work, but now it works all fine.